# ggplot2 geom_violin with 0 variance

Tags: r, ggplot2

I started to really like violin plots, since they give me a much better feel that box plots when you have funny distributions. I like to automatize a lot of stuff, and thus ran into a problem:
When one variable has 0 variance, the boxplot just gives you a line at that point. Geom_violin however, terminates with an error. What behavior would I like? Well, either put in a line or nothing, but please give me the distributions for the other variables.

Ok, quick example:

```
dff=data.frame(x=factor(rep(1:2,each=100)),y=c(rnorm(100),rep(0,100)))
ggplot(dff,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_violin()
```

yields

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "n", value = 100L) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

However, what works is:

```
ggplot(dff,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_boxplot()
```

**Update**:

The issue is resolved as of yesterday: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/972

**Update 2**:
(from question author)
Wow, Hadley himself responded! `geom_violin` now behaves consistently with `geom_density` and base R `density`.

However, I don't think the behavior is optimal yet.

*(1) The 'zero' problem*

Just run it with my original example:

```
dff=data.frame(x=factor(rep(1:2, each=100)), y=c(rnorm(100), rep(0,100)))
ggplot(dff,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_violin(trim=FALSE)
```

Yielding this:
[image]

Is the plot on the right an appropriate representation of 'all zeroes'? I don't think so. It is better to have trimming that produces a single line to show that there is no variation in the data.
Workaround solution: Add a + `geom_boxplot()`

*(2) I may actually want `TRIM=TRUE`.*

Example:

```
dff=data.frame(x=factor(rep(1:2, each=100)), y=c(rgamma(100,1,1), rep(0,100)  ))
ggplot(dff,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_violin(trim=FALSE)
```

Now I have non-zero data, and standard kernel density estimates don't handle this correctly. With `trim=T` I can quickly see that the data is strictly positive.

I am not arguing that the current behavior is 'wrong', since it's in line with other functions. However, `geom_violin` may be used in different contexts, for exploring different data.frames with heterogeneous data types (positive+skewed or not, for instance).

Comment: Seems like a reasonable thing to submit as an issue on github, especially since handling this case is probably pretty simple (although there may be strong feelings about what to display).

Comment: As a quick hack, you can set one of the y-values to 0.0001 (instead of zero) and `geom_violin` will work. You can also check out the `vioplot` package if you're not set on using `ggplot2`. `vioplot` doesn't throw an error when you feed it a bunch of identical values.

Comment: Just as another potential option, the `Hmisc` package includes a `panel.bbplot` (box-percentile plot) function that can create violin plots with the `bwplot` function from `lattice`. See the Examples section of `?panel.bpplot`. It produces a single line when you feed it a vector of identical values.

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/972).

Comment: Thanks everyone. Two comments that would qualify as solutions, at least as workarounds for my immediate issue, and someone even opened an issue. I ended up using the +0.0001 solution on a y-value, as I would expect ggplot to fix the issue in the next release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three options for dealing with this until the `ggplot2` issue is resolved:

1. As a quick hack, you can set one of the y-values to 0.0001 (instead of zero) and `geom_violin` will work.
2. Check out the `vioplot` package if you're not set on using `ggplot2`. `vioplot` doesn't throw an error when you feed it a bunch of identical values.
3. The `Hmisc` package includes a `panel.bpplot` (box-percentile plot) function that can create violin plots with the `bwplot` function from the `lattice` package. See the Examples section of `?panel.bpplot`. It produces a single line when you feed it a vector of identical values.

Comment: When you use option 1, also all other violinplots (with variance > 0) get deformated -- with a subsetting approach a workaround is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25083853/1498405