# violin plot with constant data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some weird behaviour of **violin plots**, when the **data is (in parts) constant**.

If I check for constant data and add some small errors artificially (e.g. by adding `runif( N, min = -0.001, max = 0.001 )`, the script will run. However, that distorts the other violin plot(s) to vertical line(s) (see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpUlY.png)), while it should look something like [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWEQ9.png)

**Question:**

Is it possible (when the partial data for a violin plot is constant) to

- display a simple horizontal line for the respective constant data
- display the other violin plots, as if the constant data wasn't present?

**R code:**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

N <- 20

test_data <- data.frame(
  idx  <- c( 1:N, 1:N ),
  vals <- c( runif(N, 0, 1),
             rep(  0.5, N)),                                         # <- R script won't run
             #rep( 0.5, N) + runif( N, min = -0.001, max = 0.001 )), # <- delivers graphic (distorted)
  type <- c( rep("range",  N),
             rep("const",  N))
)

grid.arrange(
  ggplot( test_data, aes( x = idx, y = vals)) + 
    geom_line( aes(colour = type)),
  ggplot( test_data, aes( x = type, y = vals)) + 
    geom_violin( aes( fill = type),
                 position = position_dodge(width = 1))
)
```

[image: distorted violin plots]

[image: the 'other' violin plot]

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129772/ggplot2-geom-violin-with-0-variance) gives some options for this issue.  You could add a variable for group variance to the dataset and then subset the dataset in `ggplot` for if the variance is greater than 0.  Adding this variable with `dplyr`: `test_data = test_data %>% group_by(type) %>% mutate(vars = var(vals))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get a violin plot with some group(s) having zero variance (standard deviation)

- to display a flat line for 0-variance groups
- display normal violin plots for other groups

[image: working violin plot with 0-variance group(s)]
[image]

In my example I have 3 groups of data - two without zero variance and the third is constant.
While accumulating the groups, I calculate the standard deviation (variance would be same functionality)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

N <- 20

test_data <- data.frame()

# random data from range
for( grp_id in 1:2)
{
    group_data <- data.frame(
      idx  = 1:N,
      vals = runif(N, grp_id, grp_id + 1),
      type = paste("range", grp_id)
    )
    group_data$sd_group <- sd( group_data$vals)
    test_data = rbind( test_data, group_data)
}

# constant data
group_data = data.frame(
    idx  = 1:N,
    vals = rep( 0.5, N),
    type = "const"
)
group_data$sd_group <- sd( group_data$vals)
```

as suggested I add a little offset to obtain a violin plot for group 'const'

```
# add a little jittering to get the flat line
if( 0 == group_data$sd_group[1])
{
    group_data$vals[1] = group_data$vals[1] + 0.00001
}
test_data = rbind( test_data, group_data)
```

Only thing now left to do is to scale all violin plots to the same width

```
grid.arrange(
    ggplot( test_data, aes( x = idx)) + 
        geom_line( aes( y = vals, colour = type)),
    ggplot( test_data, aes( x = type, y = vals, fill = type)) + 
        geom_violin( scale = "width"),
    ncol = 1
)
```

Comment: after using subset and keeping colours synchronized manually, I managed to simplify my solution to `geom_violin( scale = "width")`