# geom_violin produces error when all values in a series are the same

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

My violin plot produces an error when all values in the series are the same.

```
library(ggplot2)
d1 <- data.frame(x=c("a","a","a","b","b","b"),y=c(1,2,2,1,2,1)) # Two series of three with different values through each series
d3 <- data.frame(x=c("a","a","a","b","b","b"),y=c(1,2,2,1,1,1)) # Two series of three, one series has all the same values
ggplot(data=d1) + geom_violin(aes(x=x,y=y))                     # This works
ggplot(data=d1) + geom_violin(aes(x=x,y=y), scale="count")      # This works
ggplot(data=d3) + geom_violin(aes(x=x,y=y))                     # This produces an error: replacement has 1 row, data has 0
ggplot(data=d3) + geom_violin(aes(x=x,y=y), scale="count")      # This produces an error: replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

The first two plots work fine, the second two fail with:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "n", value = 3L) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

Is this a bug? Is there a work-around? Thanks

Comment: answer is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783826/violin-plot-with-constant-data/25083853#25083853

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that one - thanks.

Comment: Just confirming that this is a bug in v1.0.1 and has been fixed in the development version according to Hadley.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in v1.0.1 and has already been fixed in the development version according to Hadley.