# ggplot2 violin plot for columns with less than 3 samples

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I am wondering if anyone has found a way to display violin plots through ggplot2 with variables of 1 or 2 samples.

example code:

```
library(ggplot2)

testData <- data.frame(x=c("a","a","a","b","b"), y=c(1,2,2,1,2)) 
ggplot(data=testData ) + geom_violin(aes(x=x,y=y))
```

As you can see the violin plot for a has been drawn as it has 3 samples, the one for b no -> only 2 samples.

I saw [geom_violin produces error when all values in a series are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721548/geom-violin-produces-error-when-all-values-in-a-series-are-the-same) but no answer has been given, and it's been 7
years.

I know it is possible to display a violin plot with the violplot package, but I'd really prefer to keep to the ggplot package if possible.

Thanks,

HY

Comment: Your code works on my R machine, with no errors.

Comment: In the question you cited, there was a link to an answer posted:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783826/violin-plot-with-constant-data/25083853#25083853

Comment: @Marco Sandri The question can be misunderstood easily. It has nothing to do with the error quoted in the linked question. The problem here is that ggplot only plots one violin instead of two. The reason is that variable "b" has only two observations. I guess it makes no sense to plot a violin with two values and, hence, the right half of the plot remains empty. Ggplot could, however, simply indicate the two values as dots.

Comment: @ManuelPopp Thank you for your comment. Running the above code, I get 2 violins, not only 1. I am running an updated version of ggplot2.

Comment: @MarcoSandri same for me, with ggplot2 version 3.3.6 I get two violin plots and thus no errors when plotting group b with only two datapoints

Comment: @MarcoSandri Thanks a lot for your comment, may I ask which version of ggplot2 are you using?
And sorry for the ambiguity of my question. The problem is that I only have 1 violin plot appear.

Comment: I am using version 3.3.6.on R 4.1.3 (Window 10).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MarcoSandri and others.

I was on ggplot2 3.3.3, it now works on 3.3.6.